# executar calculo JQuery para cada div correspondente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

bom estou criando um sistema de classificação por estrelas mais não estou conseguindo fazer com que o jquery aplique o Width correto para cada span no exemplo abaixo eu tenho tres DIVS e cada uma das 3 divs dentro delas tem

```
<span class="ratingAverage" data-average="1.2"></span>
<span class="ratingAverage" data-average="4.2"></span>
<span class="ratingAverage" data-average="5.6"></span>
```

então com o jquery eu pego o valor de cada um do data-avarege e faz o calculo e aumenta o a barra em %

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
    var average = $('.ratingAverage').attr('data-average');

    function avaliacao(average) {
      average = (Number(average) * 20);
      $('.bg').css('width', 0);
      $('.barra .bg').animate({
        width: average + '%'
      }, 500);
    }

    avaliacao(average);
  }); <
/script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col col-12">
<div class="about">
   <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="1.2"></span>
  <span class="article" data-id=""></span>
  <div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="overhiden">
      <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col col-12">
<div class="about">
 <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="4.2"></span>
  <span class="article" data-id=""></span>
  <div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="overhiden">
      <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col col-12">
 <div class="about">
  <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="5.6"></span>
  <span class="article" data-id=""></span>
  <div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="overhiden">
      <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

o codigo do jeito que ta retorna desta maneira como na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ao invés de retornar assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o JQuery faz o calculo so da 1 div e coloca o mesmo resultado nas demais ao invés de refazer o calculo de cada uma de acordo com o valor passado no data-avarege  sou iniciante peço ajuda dos mais experientes

Comment: Diogo, primeiro de tudo aí acho que você vai ter que rever seu **HTML**  cara, tem `div` dentro de `span`. Dá uma reestruturada nisso, senão fica difícil!

Comment: eu não tinha visto ja arumei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta linha `$('.bg').css('width', 0);` me parece bem desnecessária. Por que redefinir o `width` da classe `.bg` se o código só é executado 1 vez e o `span` vazio já tem `width` `0`? Não há essa necessidade.

Minha sugestão é parecida com a do @JrD, porém um pouco mais simplificada:

```js
$(function(){
   var avg = $('.ratingAverage'); // seleciona todas as spans com a classe
   avg.each(function(i){ // percorre os elementos
      var average = Number($(this).data('average'))*20; // faz o cálculo
      $('.bg:eq('+i+')') // busca o elemento pelo index
      .animate({
         width: average + '%'
      }, 500);
   });
});
```

```css
.bg{
   background: red;
   height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col col-12">
<div class="about">
   <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="1.2"></span>
  <span class="article" data-id=""></span>
  <div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="overhiden">
      <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col col-12">
<div class="about">
 <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="4.2"></span>
  <span class="article" data-id=""></span>
  <div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="overhiden">
      <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col col-12">
 <div class="about">
  <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="5.6"></span>
  <span class="article" data-id=""></span>
  <div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="overhiden">
      <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfeito funcionou certinho eu entendo um pouco jquery sei usar as funções só não consigo e estruturar o código . obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

O jeito mais simples de resolver isso seria percorrer todos os objetos com a mesma classe e aplicar os cálculos necessários para o mesmo, segue um código exemplo de como percorrer isso.
`$(document).ready(function(){
    //PERCORRE TODOS OS OBJETOS COM A CLASSE .ratingAverage
    $(".about").each(function(){
        var average = $(this).find('.ratingAverage').data('average');
        average = (Number(average) * 20);
        $(this).find('.bg').css('width', 0);
        $(this).find('.bg').animate({
            width: average + '%'
        }, 500);
    });
});`

Comment: fiz como voce disse usando o each usando o console.log(average); retorna os valores correntos mais ao aplicar o width a cada uma ele continua a aplicar o mesmo valor em todas

Comment: @diogoDsa Fiz a alteração no código, depois dê uma verificada

Comment: Explicando as aterações... Mudei o seletou para a classe about, já que todos elementos que precisamos estão dentro dele. Para cada about é usado a função find() do JQuery para capturar outro elemento dentro do elemento atual, e apóis isso só seguindo a sequência... Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: cara você salvou minha vida já estava quase desistindo muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Cara confesso que não entendi bem o seu HTML, mas, deixo aqui uma resposta espero que te ajude a te dar um norte aí:

```js
$(function() {
    
    $('.ratingAverage').each(function(index) {
      var average = $(this).attr('data-average');
      average = average * 20;
      
      $('.bg').css('width', 0);
      
      if(index == 0) {
        $('.bg:eq(0)').animate({
          width: average + '%'
        }, 500);
      } else if(index == 1) {
        $('.bg:eq(1)').animate({
          width: average + '%'
        }, 500);
      } else if(index == 2) {
        $('.bg:eq(2)').animate({
          width: average + '%'
        }, 500);
      }

    })

});
```

```css
.bg{background-color: yellow; height: 50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col col-12">
<div class="about">
   <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="1.2"></span>
  <span class="article" data-id=""></span>
  <div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="overhiden">
      <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col col-12">
<div class="about">
 <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="4.2"></span>
  <span class="article" data-id=""></span>
  <div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="overhiden">
      <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col col-12">
 <div class="about">
  <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="5.6"></span>
  <span class="article" data-id=""></span>
  <div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="overhiden">
      <span class="stars">
      <span class="star" data-vote="1"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="2"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="3"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="4"></span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta do jeito que voce fez da certo eu dei um exemplo com 3 divs so que as div estão dentro de um foreach ou seja tem mais de três divs como faria para criar um for e aplicar em todas e nao somente as tres

Comment: Não sei qual seu conhecimento em jQuery e quantas divs são no seu código, mas, lhe aconselho aí ir fazendo **else if** como fiz, se você ver que vai ficar ruim terá que fazer **for** só que aí vai complicando mais o código.